# Calling javascript function in onsubmit

Tags: javascript, function

so I have this function defined in javascript..

```
function varReplace(formid)
{
    if (formid.factsc[0].checked == true) {
        formid.adddetails.value == "it's working";
    }
    else {
        formid.adddetails.value == "it's not working";
    }
}
```

where I want to give adddetails a certain value if the factsc in html is clicked "yes".

On the html side,  I call the function like this..

```
onsubmit="return varReplace(this.form)"
```

But it doesn't work.. any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using FireFox, you should be able to pull up any JavaScript errors with `CTRL+SHIFT+J`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning anything from your function.

> Note that in order to cancel the
>   submit event, the onSubmit should be
>   in the form onSubmit="return
>   expression". "return" indicates that
>   the value of the expression should be
>   returned to the submit routine. If the
>   expression evaluates to false, the
>   submit routine is cancelled; if it is
>   true, the submit routine goes forward.

Comment: `varReplace` doesn't have a `return`, but I'm not sure that's his problem.

Comment: I agree with Jakub, you need to be returning in the function.

Comment: @mellamokb - since onsubmit doesn't return a value that can be evaluated to `true` the actual form submit is cancelled. I suspect this is what 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Since he's setting a form control value to "it's working" or "it's not working", I would expect he's looking for that change to appear on the form, and it's not.  Just my thought.